# OpenLayers 3 retrieve view's altitude

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

I'm developing a web application that uses OpenLayers 3 and I've a service that receive 2 inputs parameters: altitude and bbox.

From the layer I can retrieve my Extent (bbox) in this way:

```
var extent = layerMap.getExtent();
```

But how can I retrieve my view's altitude?

---

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the "view's altitude"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method (not yet) to retrieve an altitude with OpenLayers 3.

The only altitude that you can get is from geolocation.
(API : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.Geolocation.html?unstable=true#getAltitude)

But if you want altitude of the center of your extent, you have the coordinates.
Then you can use an external service like this (with AngularJS, for example) :

```
        // metric system
        var altitude = 0;
        var url = 'http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/v1/profile?key=YOURKEY&latLngCollection=' + latitude + ',' + longitude;

        $http.get(url)
            .success(function (data, status) {
                altitude = data.elevationProfile[0].height;
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
            });
```